# Issue with One of Two ViewModels Not Updating with StateFlow data from same Repository in Jetpack Compose and Dagger-Hilt

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose app and using Dagger-Hilt for dependency injection. I have two ViewModels (MainViewModel and FormViewModel) subscribing to a StateFlow from a singleton AppRepository. Both ViewModels initialize correctly, but only MainViewModel is receiving updates from the repository, while FormViewModel is not. Both instances are created at same composable and time.

Notes: This application is the most extensive I've worked on using Jetpack Compose and the MVVM pattern. Initially, my app had only one ViewModel as I've always done in my compose projects, MainViewModel, which has grown significantly in size (currently about 800 lines) and is still expanding. Notably, a substantial portion of this ViewModel (approximately half) is dedicated to handling forms. My goal is to refactor this forms-related code into a separate ViewModel, leading to the creation of FormViewModel. I'm uncertain if this approach aligns with best practices in using MVVM and Dagger-Hilt. Is it advisable to maintain a single, large ViewModel, or is it acceptable to split functionalities into multiple ViewModels for better modularity and maintainability?

==============

AppRepository (summarized):

```
@Singleton
class AppRepository @Inject constructor(...) {
    private val _services = MutableStateFlow<List<LocalService>>(listOf())
    val services: StateFlow<List<LocalService>> = _services
..
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appRepository: AppRepository,
    private val application: Application
) : ViewModel() {
    val services: StateFlow<List<LocalService>> = appRepository.services

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            services.collect { ... // Logs to print services.size
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FormViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class FormViewModel @Inject constructor(private val appRepository: AppRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val services: StateFlow<List<LocalService>> = appRepository.services

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            services.collect { ... // Logs to print services.size
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Module {
...
@Provides
    fun provideMainRepository(
        ...
    ): AppRepository {
        return AppRepository(
          ...
        )
    }
```

==============
LOGS:

```
2023-11-14 11:31:16.170 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  MainViewModel init
2023-11-14 11:31:16.172 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  MainViewModel formQuestionCrossRef has changed: 0
2023-11-14 11:31:16.173 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  MainViewModel serviceFormCrossRef has changed: 0
2023-11-14 11:31:16.174 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  MainViewModel services has changed: 0
2023-11-14 11:31:16.757 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  FormViewModel init
2023-11-14 11:31:16.758 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  FormViewModel formQuestionCrossRef has changed: 0
2023-11-14 11:31:16.759 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  FormViewModel serviceFormCrossRef has changed: 0
2023-11-14 11:31:16.760 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  FormViewModel services has changed: 0
2023-11-14 11:31:20.028 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  MainViewModel services has changed: 30
2023-11-14 11:31:20.270 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  MainViewModel formQuestionCrossRef has changed: 1260
2023-11-14 11:31:20.274 15406-15406 FormViewModel           com.conecta                  D  MainViewModel serviceFormCrossRef has changed: 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `@Provides` method for `AppRepository` in the module. With that, dagger has two ways to create an instance of `AppRepository` - its `@Inject` annotated constructor and that `@Provides` method. I'm not sure which wins in the end to be honest, but I'm quite sure that the problem is that you have multiple instances of your repository.

Moreover, the `@Provides` method in a module that is installed in `SingletonComponent` doesn't mean that dagger will create only one instance of that class. For that, you will have to annotate **the method itself** with `@Singleton`. From the [docs](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html):

> Warning: A common misconception is that all bindings declared in a module will be scoped to the component the module is installed in. However, this isn’t true. Only bindings declarations annotated with a scope annotation will be scoped.

This means there are two possible solutions:

1. Remove `@Provides fun provideMainRepository()`
2. Remove `@Inject` and `@Singleton` from `AppRepository` and add `@Singleton` to `provideMainRepository()`

Answer (score -1):

About app architecture - what you probably need is a [Domain layer](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer). It wil allow you to:

- Avoid large ViewModels and improve readability
- Encapsulate complex business logic
- Improve the testability
- Have business logic that can be reused by multiple ViewModels

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)